# Backbone.js: Save Method Always Return Error Callback

Tags: php, javascript, backbone.js, callback

I know people probably will get real confused why I am not using **rails** but I feel better using php thus I've picked it. I'm basically trying to create a really simple**backbone.js**. I've predefined the **urlRoot** and **url** functions. I've coded php to just simply return me a message (using **echo**).

But no matter what I do, whenever I try receive the response it always falls to the **error** callback. I do get the **responseText** in response, however I still cannot understand why the error callback is triggered. Here is my full **html** and back-end **php** code. Why is it always going to the error callback? I would also like to state I receive header

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
```

**HTML** (also with Backbone.js inside);

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://ajax.cdnjs.com/ajax/libs/json2/20110223/json2.js"></script>
    <script src="http://ajax.cdnjs.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.1.6/underscore-min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://ajax.cdnjs.com/ajax/libs/backbone.js/0.3.3/backbone-min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div id='place'>
    <input id='clicker' type='button' value='Click Me'/>
</div>
<script type='text/javascript'>
(function($){
    Backbone.emulateHTTP=true;
    Backbone.emulateJSON=true;
    var URL=Backbone.Model.extend({
        initialize:function(){
            console.log("URL object has been created");
        },
        defaults:{
            url:'not actually defined'
        },
        urlRoot:'/StupidExample/server.php',
        url:function(){
            var base=this.urlRoot || (this.collection && this.collection.url) || "/";
            if(this.isNew()) return base;

            return base+"?id="+encodeURIComponent(this.id);
        }
    });

    var URLView=Backbone.View.extend({
        initialize:function(){
            console.log('URL View has been created');
        },
        el:('#place'),
        events:{
            "click #clicker":"alerter"
        },
        alerter:function(){
            console.log("I've been clicked");
            var obj=new URL();
            obj.save(obj.toJSON,{
            success:function(){
                console.log("Success")
            },
            error:function(model,response,xhr){
                console.log(model);
                console.log(response);
                console.log(xhr);
                console.log("Error");
            }
            });
        }
    });

    var urlView=new URLView();
})(jQuery);
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

**PHP;**

```
<?php
echo "I've received something";
?>
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You must return a valid JSON object with your `HTTP 200` response. Backbone throws an error on your `echo` return value because it tries to parse the response as JSON, which fails.

Comment: In one of my use case my server is sending a csv file, can i bypass this so that i could get the csv file in success callback. THANKS in advance.

Comment: @Trying you can always revert back to good old jQuery `ajax` method. That's what Backbone uses underneath anyways.

Answer (score 1):

As Derick said you need to return JSON, which you can do by changing your php file to:

```
 <?php print json_encode(array( 'response' => 'success' ));
```

But you will also need to not use absolute paths as your URL because AJAX is not allowed across domains so it's required to be relative.